# trying to get javascript to execute wsh through html

Tags: javascript, html, wsh

I'm stuck on this code...I'm trying to get the html page to, when you click the link, call the bsd function, which should pop up a "foo" alert. My code is below. Thanks for the help!

```js
(function() {
  var WshShell = {};
  WshShell.log = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  }

  var bsd = function BSD() {
    WshShell.log("foo");
    window.alert('foo!');
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById("bsdTrigger").addEventListener('click', bsd);
})();
```

```html
<body>
  a#bsdTrigger(href='#') foo a#ssddTrigger(href='#') bar

  <br />
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:bsd();">bsd</a>
</body>
```

Comment: How has any of the code you show anything to do with the description above? What do BSD and BMS mean? Why is there a variable called `WSHShell`? (Windows Script Host? Really?!) What does the `javascript:` prefix do in your opinion and why do you use it? In short, it's near impossible to determine what you are even talking about. Please re-write your question and add *a lot* more detail.

Comment: sorry, im new to stackoverflow...this code is part of a bigger code, adn this is the part I cant get to work. I need to include the wsh because i'll be using that part to do other stuff in the website (that I dont need to figure out since i got that part working outside of html already, so I omitted it. bsd is the function being called.

Comment: You can't execute WSH scripts from web pages.

Comment: thats what the javascript is for

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work just fine : http://jsfiddle.net/895vmsok/

```
<a href="#" id="bsdTrigger" onclick="javascript:bsd();">bsd</a>
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your need here?

Comment: thanks! maybe its just my browswer at home? I'll try it (again) once I get back

Comment: well, I did add the "id" to the element. Your code didn't have that